# To solve $ \int_{a}^{b}J_{0}(x)dx$ where $J_{0}(x)$ is Bessel function of first kind and order zero:

Tags: bessel-functions

I am attempting to solve this integral analytically,
$$
\int_{a}^{b}J_{0}(x)dx
$$
Here $J_{0}(x)$ is the Bessel function of first kind and order zero. How does one decide upon the infinite value of summation of this function to solve this integral?

Comment: There is an explicit solution for the antiderivative.

Comment: Could you please show it to me? Also kindly suggest me some books to understand the basic operations, differentiation and integration of Bessel functions of first kind.

Comment: Use http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E2 or http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E8

Comment: Thank YOU! @Gary